# COM port lockup with Mbed Virtual Serial Port

Tags: serial-port, mbed

I am working with someone using Mbed and a LPCXpresso11U68 board.

I'm not intimately familiar with this particular board, but it has two USB connectors on it, one for the OpenSDA-ish debugger, and a second one is a direct connect to the CPU.  I can connect both of these ports to my PC and attach a terminal emulator to each of them, and both ports show output (with a small installed program running on the board).
The device manager shows me that one port (COM51) is using "mbed Serial Port" driver and the other port (COM52) is using "Mbed Virtual Serial Port.
So far so good...

There is a reset button on the board.  If I press that button, the port that is attached to the PC using the Mbed Virtual Serial Port driver (in my case COM52) stops operating.  The other port (COM51) just restarts cleanly.

The problem I'm having is that after I exit the terminal program (note this happens with both TeraTerm and uCon), if I attempt to reconnect to that port, its not in the list of available comports.  Strangely thought, it is still present in the Device Manager.
The only way I've found that I can clear this problem is to unplug/plug that usb cable (COM52) or issue a BREAK condition to COM51 (which AFAIK, resets the board).

I am the writer of uCon and I'd like to be able to detect this (which I can), and also be able to restart the comport connection without any other manual intervention.

One final note: apparently this is not specific to the LPCXpresso11U68 board; my guess it is some issue with the Mbed Virtual Serial Port driver.

Anyone have a clue what may be going on here?